# Clear radiobutton list selection using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, jquery, csom, client-side-rendering

I would like to clear Radiobutton list selection once user click the button. I have tried the following code but clears the selection in browser.
When I access from backend(C#) selection is there. It doesn't clear the selection of the control really I guess. Any suggestion please.

```
<SharePoint:DVRadioButtonList ID="rblLst" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
</SharePoint:DVRadioButtonList>
<br/><input type="button" id="btnClearrblfinance" value="Clear Selection" onclick="ClearSelectionrblfinance()" />
```

JQuery to clear the control

```
$("table[id$=rblLst] input:radio:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$("table[id$=rblLst] input:radio:checked").prop('checked', false);
```

**OR**

```
$("#btnClearrblfinance").prop('checked', false);
```

Refer this link - https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#attributes

Comment: rohit-waghela, in my case functionality working in browser. But it doesn't reflect in code behind.